# Play videos automatically in Raspberry Pi Qt

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi

I want to play videos on Raspberry Pi which built Qt as well. thing is i have try out a example on github [link](http://github.com/carlonluca/pi) but it seems to be not working for me. I want to play videos using omx player automatically once i have uploaded a xml config file
 any clue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use omxplayer, then you should checkout it here: https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer. I see from the code it can be controlled using a pipe.

EDIT: omxplayer also has a dbus interface.